# Detect Form Complete JQuery

Tags: jquery

i have a form which is within a div, the form contains an input type=file. I submit the form using

```
$("#div form").submit();
```

but i want to detect when the form has actually completed submitting. I have tried:

```
$("#div form").submit(function()
{
 alert("submitted")
});
```

But this didnt seem to work, the form was no longer submitted and i wouldn't get the alert either.

Then i tried:

```
$("#div form").submit(showalert());

function showalert()
{
 alert("show");
}
```

this then showed the alert but still didnt submit.

Anything I'm missing?

Thanks

Marcel.

Comment: SUbmitting the form with ajax?

Comment: there should be a callback function in submit()'s detail. unminify that .js file and use alerts or debugs in that function

Comment: I started with a code sample on jsFiddle. You can take a look on it by going to http://jsfiddle.net/NyfTW/2/. The current version seems to work without a problem. You can edit it to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
$("#div form").submit(function(){ 
    alert("submitted");
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks for the input. just tried it, still does not submit though :(

Comment: @Marcel: Please see amended answer.  Also, could you post your `form` declaration code?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not doing the submission with ajax, then you are redirected to the submission page, so there is no way to handle completion (*it does not apply to the concept*).

Using a function argument in the `.submit()` method, simply binds that function to be called when the form is submitted (*not completed, but when the submission starts, when you click the submit button or trigger it with a method*)

If you are using ajax to submit, then you can use the `success` event of the ajax to know when the ajax has finished, which means it got a response from the server..

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you haven't actually calle dthe form submit.

```
$("#div form").submit(showalert);
$("#div form").submit();

function showAlert() {
    alert("show");
    return true;
}
```

$("#div form").submit(showalert); just specifies what that when the form does submit you want to run showalert() however it does not DO the submit.  To do the submit call $("#div form").submit();

Hope it works for you